# PHP: Get within a String the Text and search for the String in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a String: `$lang['home']`

and would like to search them with SQL in the database. I want to browse it like this:

```
select * from languages where name = 'home'
```

How do I get the text "Home" From the String so that I can query this with PHP in the database? I want to get the value of `'Home'` if I run the Code  `$lang['home']`

I have try with Foreach() But unfortunately I didn't manage it.

Comment: You mean there are names in the database and you need to find one of them which contains the word 'home'?